# How to run python code at the background without impacting rendering of html template?

Tags: python, django, speech-recognition

#### Concept that I want to achieve:

A web application that listens to user's speech at the background and do what the user wants.

#### What I have:

A Python - Django application with Speech Recognition enabled with the following two files.

- speechrecognition.py (This is where speech recognition related logic is)
- index.html

#### Note: speechrecognition.py goes on a loop repeatedly listening to user's input.

#### What I tried:

I tried calling speechrecognition.py class before rendering index.html in views.py

```
from SpeechRegApp.speechrecognition import SpeechRecognition

def index(request):  
    SpeechRecognition() 
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

#### Problem that I'm facing:

Since I'm repeatedly listening to user's input in speechrecognition.py, index.html doesn't get rendered.

#### How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you considered ```django-celery```? For asynchronous tasks like this.

Comment: Thank you. No. I didn't know that there is something like that. I'm new to Python - Django

Comment: I've shared the set link in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

This totally make sense, since your code is trapped in that loop. 
There is a module in python called "threading"!
I am not sure, but maybe that module can help you putting your SpeechRecognition() to background, while the rest of your code proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this [link](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/). It will show you how to set up background task with Django, Celery and Redis.

This will enable to to run your `SpeechRecognition()` in parallel with your existing code.

Example:
**views.py**

```py
from SpeechRegApp.speechrecognition import SpeechRecognition

def index(request):  
    speech_recognition_task.delay()
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

**celery.py**

```py
@celery.task
def file_transfer():
    SpeechRecognition()
```

Hope this helps.